# Want to improve innodb insertion performance

Tags: c++, performance, mariadb, innodb, insertion

I have 24 gb ram , centos 7 Os , mariadb 10.3 Version database and 1TB ssd linux server and i am running my cpp script and mariacpp connector to insert data in tables and i have around 50000 tables and want to insert data only in 5000 tables from those 50000 tables but when i run my script using cpp threading and mariacpp connector i get only 50 insertion / sec . Which is very low so i want to improve InnoDb insertion performance. So Please suggest me any configurations and any other ways.
My Current InnoDB Configurations :

```
Innodb_read_io_threads=64;
innodb_write_io_threads=64  ;
innodb_buffer_pool_size=16G;
innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup=ON;
innodb_log_file_size = 1G ;
innodb_log_files_in_group=10;
innodb_file_per_table=1;
innodb_log_buffer_size=1G;
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT;
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2;
skip-innodb_doublewrite ;
innodb_io_capacity = 2000;
innodb_io_capacity_max = 3000;
innodb_flush_sync=1;
```

I tried many thing related variables but not improved and i changed my all tables from MyISAM to InnoDB using Alter table query.

Answer (score 0):

```
innodb_log_buffer_size=1G
```

That may be dangerously high.  Lower it to 1% of RAM.

Having 50K tables is usually a bad schema design pattern; please explain what you are doing.

There are multiple ways to do fast `INSERTs`:

- `LOAD DATA INFILE` -- but only if you already have the data in a CSV file.
- Batched `INSERT` -- `INSERT INTO t (...) VALUES (1,2), (3,4), ...` -- Above 1000 rows at a time you get into "diminishing returns and other inefficiencies.
- Putting several `INSERTs` into a single transaction.  This also has issues with diminishing returns and inefficiencies.

Which of those have you employed?  (Then we can critique things further.)

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for one of the tables.  There may be clues on what would help.  (One example:  lots of unnecessary indexes.)

Describe your disk subsystem -- HDD vs SSD; RAID; etc.